# Change string locale

Tags: c++, string, stl

I'm not very familiar with locale-specific conversions so I may be using the wrong terminology here. This is what I want to have happen.

I want to write a function

```
std::string changeLocale( const std::string& str, const std::locale& loc )
```

such that if I call this function as follows:

```
changeLocale( std::string( "1.01" ), std::locale( "french_france" ) )
```

the output string will be "1,01"

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is no such thing as "string locale". A locale is a set of formatting rules and other parameters that reflect user's language and culture. A string is a sequence of characters. One may use a locale when creating a string out of some other data. Once it is created, there is no locale associated with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this ought to do the trick

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
int main (int argc,char** argv) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.imbue(std::locale("fr_FR.UTF8"));
    double value = 1.01; 
    ss << value; 
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Should give you output of `1,01` (at least it does on g++).  You might have to fiddle with the locale specification since it's very specific to platform.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that does the trick for numeric values on VS2008. I did have to fiddle with the locale specification like you said; the only thing I could get to work was 
    std::locale( "french_france" )

Anyway, this solution only works for numeric data. What if my input string was "I weigh 200.5 lbs" and I wanted the output to be "I weigh 200,5 lbs"? Is this possible at all?

Comment: Well, 200.5 is a number too right?  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: What I meant to ask if how do I handle string inputs. For example the following doesn't work:

    stringstream ss;
    ss.imbue( locale( "french_france" ) );
    string s( "I weigh 200.5 lbs" );
    ss << s.c_str(); 
    wcout << ss.str() << endl; 

The 200.5 in the input remains the same in the output string and I want the output string to be "I weigh 200,5 lbs"

Comment: I was looking to help out on this only to discover that std::locale is busted in a big way on Mac OS X: it only accepts locale names "C" and "POSIX".  This seems to be true for at least 10.4 to 10.6.  You can still grab the current locale and override various traits; however, you can't load a predefined locale like "fr_FR".

Comment: @praetorian: If the number is jumbled up in a string, then I think the only option is to take the string apart and get the number, format it, and put it back together again.

Comment: Crap! I was afraid you'd say that. That seems like it would be hard to make it foolproof; but I'm gonna give it a try. Thanks for your help Jeff.

Comment: @Praetorian "I weigh 200,5 lbs". Why not "Je pèse 90,9 kg"? Be realistic, demand the impossible ;)

Comment: @n.m. I asked this almost 7 years ago. I was just starting out with C++ and was hoping for some kind of magic :)

Comment: @Praetorian I always fail to look at post dates :(